# How to find which updates failed in "Windows Update"

Tags: drivers, windows-update

I just got a new laptop and was installing all the Windows updates (including driver updates) to it.  One of the driver updates failed.  Windows update tells me that one did, but not which one (other than it was a driver update and maybe I have a better one already installed, but it will keep trying).  I looked through update history, but cannot find one listed as failed.

I just want to turn off that update and not have it keep trying.  But I don't know how to find which one it was, nor how to turn it off.

Exact message:

A current driver on your PC may be better than the driver we're trying to install. We'll keep trying to install.

(And, I just want to say, stop trying....)

Comment: No, and  I looked at the windows update history and there are no updates listed as failing.  Only the cryptic message at the top level "checking for updates" screen with a red "retry" button.  And, now I don't want to retry (although I did try that a couple times).  I just want to cancel whatever update is failing.....

Comment: The current driver message in Windows Update is annoying, but doesn't cause any actual problems, that I have observed. As it applies to a driver it isn't a "Windows Update" that is failing, just one of the option Drive Updates.

Answer (score 0):

"wushowhide.diagcab" has been deprecated by Microsoft and to the best of my knowledge, you can no longer hide updates.

Microsoft uses the WER reports to fix the problem at their end.

Find the Driver Update app for your computer and make sure all drivers including BIOS are up to date. That may (or may not) clear the problem.

Otherwise, leave it be and it will clear eventually.

Comment: I was trying to install driver updates when I got this message.  That's how I got into this situation in the first place. Now, I want to know which driver I was trying to install that it couldn't and cancel its update.

Comment: You may just have to wait for the message to clear - Out of band Windows Update or Patch Tuesday next.

Comment: Oh, well, frustrating....   Thanks.

Comment: What you see ("Retry") has happened to me and it took a Microsoft update to clear it. Yes, it can be frustrating.  Also do not hesitate to use the Feedback Hub to register the problem.